# What type of view is it?

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

This is a money manager app from Play Store. When clicking on the left arrow on the action bar, it will jump to another page and show the record of last month. I would like to do something like this in android.

May I know what kind of view is it? Is it RecyclerView? What kind of implementation will be the best for user experience when I want to change the content of page?

Comment: I think, thats simply button-textview-button group

Answer (score 0):

I seems to be just a simple toolbar which has some child views. 
In this case:

```
<Toolbar>
  <LinearLayout>
    <ImageView>
    <TextView>
    <ImageView>
  <LinearLayout>
<Toolbar>
```

The structure of layouts below it is also clear. It is a TabLayout & Viewpager.The black layout with icons on the bottom is not nice (it is not matching MaterialGuidelines.).There should rather be a drawer which would have these options which are located in the black layout.

Comment: Actually I am interested to know how to make the transition from page to page smooth?

Comment: OK. You mean the transition which is triggered when arrows in toolbar are clicked? There is a ViewPager method for that. Swiping is also handled automaticaly. You probably never used it before... You should read some article about TabLayout and ViewPager first. Try this one: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/